# Jquery Mobile: Getting a cancelled Postback that's causing a page load error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery-mobile, postback

So, I've been trying to get this page working for a couple of days now, when I clicked the send button it would work, but if you tried to hit enter it would just do a postback to the same page.  Yesterday I thought I finally got it so it would work on chrome (it has been working just fine on firefox, but breaking on chrome/safari and it is an app for the iphone).  But, even though I finally got it so it would change pages, it is now displaying an error.  I narrowed down the cause to a postback that is being called right before the postback I want is being sent which is then cancelled.  I assume the cancelled postback is blank because the problem I was having was the page would do a blank postback.

I 'fixed' the problem by adding

```
javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) __doPostBack('" & btnSearch.UniqueID & "','')
```

to the onKeyPress for txtSearch.  The ending html for the asp:LinkButton and asp:TextBox (which is enclosed in an asp:Panel, inside an asp:Content for a master page which is inside a form, may or may not be relevant) is

```
<input name="ctl00$contentMain$txtSearch" id="contentMain_txtSearch" type="text" data-type="search" onkeypress="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) __doPostBack('ctl00$contentMain$btnSearchByIDName','')" class="...">

<a id="contentMain_btnSearch" class="..." data-role="button" onclientclick="return false;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$contentMain$btnSearch','')" data-theme="c"><span class="..."><span class="...">Search</span></span></a>
```

There is an on button click event in the code behind.

This is the header from the post, the response and everything else is empty.

```
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:Local.Website
Referer:Local.Website/EmployeePhoneList/PhoneList.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Anyone have any ideas how to figure out why it is doing two postbacks?  Or how I could determine what is causing it?  Thanks for any help.

Update: Looking further into the response, btnSearch is the origin for both the incorrect and correct postbacks.  Also, things that **HAVE NOT** worked, AutoPostBack="false", CauseValidation="false", ViewStateMode="Disabled" and UseSubmitBehavior="false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While fixing an seemingly unrelated problem on another page we accidentally fixed the problem.  Turns out even with ajaxEnabled = false, you sometimes need to put data-ajax="false" in the form of the masterpage to make asp.net code work correctly with JQuery mobile.  Either that or rc1 fixed the problem, I don't know for sure and at this point I don't really care anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried disabling jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation? Here's how I did it in an MVC project, should be similar in WebForms:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
       $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
   });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, we have ajax disabled in that way on both the master pages for the webapp (two site names, intranet and extranet).  Although yesterday I did have to change it to the new way because I realized that we had it set up for back in Alpha so it was $.mobile.AjaxFormsEnabled = False;  That didn't fix the problem though.