# ASP.NET button postback not working is JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have looked at several solutions on SO but none seem to work or don't address JQuery-Mobile, If I commment out `Mobile` the postback works fine and update is accepted.

I have an ASP.net page that i have added JQuery and Datepicker widget. - when adding JQuery Mobile JS to the page the mobile page works fine and the Datepicker has an added JS file to make it function as well. However the button in the page is not working, I have narrowed it down to `jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script-->
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/master/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Button is within an `<InsertItemTemplate>`

```
        </InsertItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
                    FDID:
                    <asp:Label ID="FDIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FDID") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    CHOICE1:
                    <asp:Label ID="CHOICE1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CHOICE1") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    CHOICE2:
                    <asp:Label ID="CHOICE2Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CHOICE2") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    CHOICE3:
                    <asp:Label ID="CHOICE3Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CHOICE3") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    CHOICE4:
                    <asp:Label ID="CHOICE4Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CHOICE4") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    CHOICE5:
                    <asp:Label ID="CHOICE5Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CHOICE5") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    CHOICE6:
                    <asp:Label ID="CHOICE6Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CHOICE6") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    IPADDRESS:
                    <asp:Label ID="IPADDRESSLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IPADDRESS") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    PICKDATE:
                    <asp:Label ID="PICKDATELabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PICKDATE") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                        Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                        Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New"
                        Text="New"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>   
    </asp:FormView>
```

not sure if it has anything to do with:
`ui-btn-active`
in the `mobile.js`

Comment: Disable Ajax by adding `data-ajax="false"` to button.

Comment: just found that but had to put it prior to `mobile.js` loading...

Comment: only issue now is... its shows as a mobile look in safari desktop - but my datepicker no longer works in desktop Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530184/jquery-mobile-getting-a-cancelled-postback-thats-causing-a-page-load-error mentions the need to also put `data-ajax="false"` in the `<form>` for the masterpage to make it work? how is that formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this resolved the issue after further search.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/master/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Had to change from CDN connections for scripts and css to locally stored js files - This fixed issue with desktop browsers not working with JQuery Mobile - due to https: mixed with non-secure script connection that blocked script.